# Python. How to plot regression lines per groupby object in separate axes using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, linear-regression, subplot

Here is my dataset with:

- 3 surveys (exp1, exp2 and exp3)
- Each survey contains 2 trials (trial1,trial2)
- The trials were evaluated using 3 features (feature1, feature2 and feature2)
  I'm investigating the association of each feature with the target variable per survey and per trial. I used a regression model. I'm able to generate individual figure for each survey and trial. However, because there are 3 features per survey/trial, I would like to generate a figure with 1 row and 3 columns so that all the 3 features are on the same figure like in the attached desired output. Ideally, the plots will be saved in a single pdf file.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from scipy import stats

data = {'Trial': ['trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial1', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2', 'trial2'],
        'Survey': ['exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp1', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp2', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3', 'exp3'],
        'feature1': [0.76, 0.72, 0.76, 0.73, 0.69, 0.76, 0.74, 0.71, 0.67, 0.74, 0.74, 0.68, 0.73, 0.67, 0.63, 0.73, 0.72, 0.7, 0.59, 0.7, 0.63, 0.52, 0.57, 0.49, 0.46, 0.59, 0.59, 0.55, 0.42, 0.55, 0.69, 0.75, 0.72, 0.8, 0.79, 0.69, 0.65, 0.73, 0.68, 0.8, 0.79, 0.79, 0.76, 0.52, 0.6, 0.53, 0.71, 0.71, 0.71, 0.64, 0.53],
        'feature2': [0.59, 0.55, 0.6, 0.56, 0.51, 0.6, 0.54, 0.51, 0.48, 0.57, 0.65, 0.57, 0.63, 0.56, 0.51, 0.64, 0.6, 0.56, 0.46, 0.6, 0.48, 0.36, 0.4, 0.32, 0.3, 0.43, 0.41, 0.36, 0.26, 0.38, 0.49, 0.57, 0.53, 0.65, 0.64, 0.5, 0.52, 0.61, 0.55, 0.75, 0.73, 0.73, 0.65, 0.34, 0.43, 0.35, 0.58, 0.58, 0.57, 0.48, 0.34],
        'feature3': [0.32, 0.28, 0.29, 0.28, 0.25, 0.3, 0.29, 0.28, 0.24, 0.28, 0.28, 0.23, 0.24, 0.22, 0.2, 0.25, 0.25, 0.24, 0.19, 0.23, 0.22, 0.17, 0.18, 0.16, 0.16, 0.19, 0.2, 0.19, 0.15, 0.18, 0.27, 0.31, 0.27, 0.35, 0.35, 0.25, 0.23, 0.26, 0.23, 0.32, 0.3, 0.31, 0.28, 0.2, 0.21, 0.19, 0.25, 0.24, 0.24, 0.21, 0.2],
        'target': [91, 88, 87, 87, 86, 89, 85, 86, 85, 87, 91, 88, 87, 87, 86, 89, 85, 86, 85, 87, 91, 88, 87, 87, 86, 89, 85, 86, 85, 87, 85, 88, 87, 93, 94, 86, 85, 88, 87, 93, 94, 91, 90, 85, 88, 87, 93, 94, 91, 90, 83]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


with PdfPages(f'regplot_example.pdf') as pdf:
    for surveyTrial, data in df.groupby(['Survey','Trial']):
        regResult_perSurvey = dict() # will create a DF later from this dict
        survey,trial = surveyTrial
        print(f'processing: {surveyTrial}')

        for feature in ['feature1','feature2','feature3']:
            #fitting the regression model
            slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(data[feature],data[target])
            regResult_perSurvey[f'{survey}:{trial}:{feature}'] = [survey,trial,feature,f'{r_value:.2f}',f'{p_value:.2e}',f'{std_err:.2f}']

            #Plotting
            ax = sns.regplot(x=feature,y=target,data = data,\
                             scatter_kws={'color':'black'},\
                             line_kws={'color':'red','label':"y={0:.1f}x+{1:.1f}\n$R^2: {2:.2f}$".format(slope,intercept,r_value)})

            ax.set_title(f'{survey} {trial} {feature}')
            ax.legend()
            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.savefig(f'regplot_{survey}_{trial}_{feature}.png')# individual plots
            pdf.savefig()#But I want all 3 features in the same figure
            
            plt.close()
```

Here is my desired output. Thank you inadvance for helping me out.
[image: the 3 feaures of the df.groupby(['Survey','Trial']) should be on the same row]

Comment: `dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['Trial', 'Survey', 'target'], var_name='Feature')` and `g = sns.lmplot(data=dfm, x='value', y='target', row='Trial', col='Survey', hue='Feature')`

Comment: I would do: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1CTr.png).

Comment: Hi Trenton, that's great. I'm trying to get a sense of your code. The 3 surveys of each trial are side by side on the same row, which is good. I like that. The final thing would be to get the plots of each trial on a separate page in the pdf file, such as trial1 on page 1, trial2 on page2 and so on. I have dozen of trial. Anyway, thank you so much for your time and so hepful assistance.